# Fluent UI PeoplePicker onChange

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to use the PeoplePicker control on Fluent UI:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/peoplepicker

How can I trigger an action when a selection is made? I don't see any onChange method or similar exposed in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at class inheritance on Fluent UI, I found out that the people picker was built on top of a "[base picker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers)".

The base picker page has more details on event handlers, including for example an "onItemSelected" method.